# WPF multithreading binding MVVM

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, binding

Im new to WPF (coming from Windows Forms background). I have an Image control with binding to BitmapSource property.The bitmap is updated on a seperate thread. I get an error regarding dependency object must be on the same thread...how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) in order to update the UI from another thread.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
    () => UpdateMyUIElement(withSomeArgs);
);
```

There is a pretty detailed [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) covering this topic.